# Know for how long request waited in Tomcat queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

We are working on a product which uses heterogeneous set of backend tools. REST API is primarily in Python, and then sometimes Python needs to call Java server synchronously via REST. We need some metrics which help us understand if Java server is overloaded and we need one more Java container. Number of busy threads or CPU utilization by Java process are good ones, but I would like to see for how long (and if at all) requests sit in Tomcat queue before they start being executed by Tomcat thread pool. In asynchronous scenario involving RabbitMQ, those metrics come with RabbitMQ, but I'm talking about synchronous scenario.

And now the most interesting part begins. I cannot find a way to be notified about the message hitting accept thread, or being placed into waiting queue. All I can have is notification when message is about to begin being processed, via extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` and implementing `preHandle` method (I use Spring Boot). I intentionally reduced number of worker threads to 1 and sent 3 requests every two seconds, sleeping 10 seconds in my REST handler. This test shows that `HandlerInterceptorAdapter.preHandle` is called exactly before thread starts executing the request, not when Tomcat queued the request because all threads are busy.

This looks logical, because if all threads are busy, how would Tomcat let us know that request has been queued? By executing some code provided by us? In context of what thread if all are busy? I have tried Filter but it also did not help with the same symptoms. It gets fired immediately before the Interceptor.

Is it ever possible to achieve what I want without adding time request has been produced to HTTP headers? I'm reluctant with going that way because time can be set incorrectly on machines hosting containers, or, even worse, it can fluctuate few seconds forth and back.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.